# What advantages does C++20's std::source_location have over the pre-defined macros __FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__?

Tags: c++, c++20

In my current project, I have used:

```cpp
Log(__LINE__, __FUNCTION__, message);
```

But the new C++20 utility class `std::source_location`
comes with functions `line()`, `column()`, `file_name()`, `function_name()`, which do the same thing. So, the new C++20 way would be:

```cpp
log(std::string message,const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << "Debug:"
              << location.file_name() << ':'
              << location.line() << ' '
              << message << '\n';
}
```

What is the advantage of the new, C++20 way over the old standard double-underscore macros, `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__func__`, which have already been standard C++ for a long time?

I'm trying to decide if the advantage(s) are so great as to justify modifying the code in my current projects to use the new `std::source_location` object in preference to the macros.

Comment: Macros can be dangerous.  They live outside the type system and can be very hard to debug.  The C++20 way OTOH, exits in the type system and is easier to debug.

Comment: Full discussion with example at [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pre-C++20 you had to choose between being verbose (passing `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__func__` to each call manually) and using a macro to do that for you.

`std::source_location` gives you a nice calling syntax without a macro. There are no other hidden advantages.

Note that both Clang, GCC, and MSVC have the same non-standard extension that lets you do it pre-C++20: `__builtin_LINE()`, `__builtin_FILE()`, and `__builtin_FUNCTION()` that can be used as default arguments to achieve the same effect. You should be able to write your own `class source_location` using them as well.

Comment: you could make your own `struct SourceLocation { int line; char const* file, func; };`. But now it's standard, so it's good.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili You can't mimic `std::source_location::current()` in standard C++. Not without GCC's `__builtin_LINE()` or equivalent.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `std::source_location` needs compiler support to work.  It can't be implemented in pure C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `SourceLocation current = { __LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNC__ };`. Then send this object to the logging routine. Not automatic, but yeah.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: And what line/file/func will it get? It depends on where that is, and for default parameters, it isn't necessarily where that argument is initialized.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, it won't work for default arguments. You have to create it on-site and send manually (or have a macro do it for you).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Hence the answer :-)

Comment: @Sneftel I misunderstood the answer initially. I thought the point was that it's a nicely packaged type. Looks like the point was you don't need to type `__LINE__` and other verbose macros.

Answer (score 23):

Your example is the best motivation I can think of. In the past `__LINE__` and `_FILE__` were the best excuse to use macros for debug logs. Now this does not hold anymore.

In the past you had basically two choiches. Either let the caller pass info on where the logging happens:

```
log(__LINE__,__FILE__,"Hello World");
```

or use a macro to get same output via

```
log("Hello World");
//^--- log must be a macro if we want this __LINE__ in the log
```

Both is very inconvenient, because either the user has to pass parameters that have to be the same anyhow on each call, or we need to use a macro with all the known downsides. With `source_location` we can get `log("Hello World");` without any macros involved, but still include line and file of the call, because default parameters are substituted at the call site. For example:

```
#include <source_location>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void log(std::string message,const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << "Debug:"
              << location.file_name() << ':'
              << location.line() << ' '
              << message << '\n';
}


int main() {
    log("hello");
    log("world");
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/K5Ec7874h):

```
Debug:/app/example.cpp:15 hello
Debug:/app/example.cpp:16 world
```

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of std::source_location is mostly convenience, because it represents a source location with a single, easily storable structure.

It has also the advantage of not being based on preprocessor magic, so for the language it is not just an integer literal but a valid type, which is much nicer from the point of view of type-safety.

If you are fine with the older approach, there's no reason to change good, already working code. This is generally true for most new features though, not only for std::source_location.

Comment: Um, an integer literal has a valid type. And `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` aren't "preprocessor magic", unless you regard the entire preprocessor as magic.

Comment: @PeteBecker the preprocessor *is* fundamentally "magic", given that it happens even before parsing and can be separated from the main building process into a different step (i.e. by running `cpp` or `cc -E`). Thus, macros like `__LINE__` completely lose their semantic meaning because the compiler only sees raw values, not identifiers. There is no way to differentiate an integer literal from `__LINE__`, and it can even be used in contexts it's not valid, given that the substitution happens at a textual level.

Comment: If you believe that the possibility of separating compilation into separate phases shows some deep meaning, keep in mind that the C++ standard describes compilation in nine separate phases, which can be implemented separately and sequentially. Back in the olden days, compilers were implemented as three or four separate executables, run sequentially by a driver; each phase wrote its results into an intermediate file, and the next phase got its input from the file generated by the preceding phase.