# How to print the current filename with a function defined in another file without using macros?

Tags: c++, filenames, inline

Is it possible to print the caller source file name calling a function defined in another file, without passing `__FILE__` explicitly and without using preprocessor tricks?

```
// Header.h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Log1(string msg) {
   cout << __FILE__ << msg << endl;   // this prints "Header.h"
}

void Log2(string file, string msg) {
   cout << file << msg << endl;
}

inline void Log3(string msg) {
   cout << __FILE__ << msg << endl;   // this prints "Header.h"
}


// Source.cpp

#include "Header.h"

int main()
{    
    Log1(" Test 1");
    Log2(__FILE__, " Test 2");
    Log3(" Test 3");
}
```

With this code, this is what I get:

```
pathTo\Header.h Test 1
pathTo\Source.cpp Test 2
pathTo\Header.h Test 3
```

I would have expected the last call to print: `pathTo\Source.cpp Test 3`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding `inline`. It means "there can be multiple definitions in multiple Translation Units". That means it's intended for the linker. The preprocessor doesn't even notice the token.

Comment: Dupe: [What advantages does C++20's std::source_location have over the pre-defined macros __FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970038/what-advantages-does-c20s-stdsource-location-have-over-the-pre-defined-macr/67971576#67971576)

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location):

```cpp
// library.h
#pragma once
#include <source_location>
#include <string>

void Log(std::string msg, const std::source_location loc =
                                std::source_location::current());
```

```cpp
// library.cpp
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

void Log(std::string msg, const std::source_location loc) {
    std::cout << loc.file_name() << ' '<< msg << '\n';
}
```

```cpp
// Source.cpp
#include "library.h"

int main() {    
    Log("Test 1"); // Prints "Source.cpp Test 1"
}
```

This requires C++20. Prior to C++20 you can use [`boost::source_location`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/assert/source_location.hpp).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. The only issue is that it requires C++20, which I cannot use, yet, because of project requirements... Please, let me know if anything with C++17 exists, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Pietro I added a note about the requirement and  a possible way to get very similar functionality in C++17.

Comment: Wow, such a magic is now available in C++!